# Syntax error or access violation with proper query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to run some custom script from ssh console which gives me back this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bf_company_banner_store2(`banner_id` varchar(10),`stor' at line 1, query was: SELECT * FROM `bf_setup_module`;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bf_company_banner_store2(`banner_id` varchar(10),`store_id` varchar(10));

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
`bf_setup_module`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bf_company_banner_store2(`banner_id` varchar(10),`store_id` varchar(10));
```

But if I run the exact the same query inside phpmyadmin it works fine. 
What could be the reason for this error, the query seems ok?

Comment: One reason why an access violation would be reported would be the use of reserved keyword.

Comment: did you put semicilon at the end ?

Comment: @JigneshRawal but if you check the query there doesn't seem to be eny reserved keyword inside. And the weird thing is that the same query works fine if I put it directly into phpmyadmin.

Comment: @safinchacko Yes there is semicolon at the end.

Comment: @user1324762 it looks to me like an issue with the back ticks. can you retry working with quotes ?

Comment: @JigneshRawal still the same.